# Multiple consecutive AJAX calls in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I currently have an app where visitors signup through an AJAX form using devise.

I want to enhance this form and do the following:

1. When the user is on the page, a modal with a subscription choice appears.
2. Once he submits this form, the signup form shows up.
3. Once he filled in the form and submitted it, the payment form (+ recap of the chosen subscription) appears.
4. Once the user paid, he is redirected.

So I was thinking about three consecutive AJAX calls to do so, but I'm stuck.

Here is what I did for the first part (to get from the subscription choice form to the signup form):

meals/index.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user == nil %>
  <%= render partial: 'subscriptions/subscription_selection' %>
<% end %>
```

subscriptions/_subscription_selection.html.erb:

```
<!-- some blabla -->
<%= form_tag save_subscription_choice_path, method: "get", remote: true do %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'chosen_subscription', '22'%>
          <%= submit_tag 'CHOISIR CETTE FORMULE', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <% end %>
```

subscription_controller.rb:

```
  def save_subscription_choice
    @subscription_choice_id = params['chosen_subscription']
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
get "subscriptions/save_subscription_choice", to: "subscriptions#save_subscription_choice", as: "save_subscription_choice"
```

subscriptions/save_subscription_choice.js.erb:

```
$(".subscription-selection-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'meals/signup_modal') %>");

console.log('save_subscription_choice.js.erb succesfully loaded');
```

and the error logs are:

```
Started GET "/subscriptions/save_subscription_choice?utf8=%E2%9C%93&chosen_subscription=12&commit=CHOISIR+CETTE+FORMULE" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-29 15:48:04 +0200
Processing by SubscriptionsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "chosen_subscription"=>"12", "commit"=>"CHOISIR CETTE FORMULE", "id"=>"save_subscription_choice"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-29 15:48:04 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as JS
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
```

I have no clue why does the app calls /users/sign_in.js, it isn't even in my own code (probably a devise file I guess ?)

Any Idea on How I could make this work ?

Comment: Some before_action is preventing the first request to work because it's not authorized: `Completed 401 Unauthorized`. Then devise redirect you to sign you up. It look you are requiring an actual logged in user on `save_subscription_choice` action.

Comment: @arieljuod thank you for your help ! I tried to add `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, raise: false, only: [:save_subscription_choice]` to my Subscription controller, but I still get the same error.  Maybe have I added it in the wrong place ?

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: I just found out the issue. thank you very much for your help, the devise authorisation was actually part of the problem too !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it was actually a router issue.

in my `config/routes.rb` the routes of subscriptions#index and subscriptions#show were mentionned first:

```
  resources :subscriptions, only: [:index, :show]
    get "subscriptions/save_subscription_choice", to: "subscriptions#save_subscription_choice", as: "save_subscription_choice"
```

Which was making my app actually call the show method.

I simply switched these two lines, and it now works perfectly.

as pointed out by @arieljuod, Second problem was: devise authorisation.

As the authentication of the user,  before_action, is set to true by default in my app, I had to add the following line in my subscription controller: `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, raise: false, only: [:save_subscription_choice]`